# how to create 8bit jpeg in gd using php

Tags: php, gd, jpeg

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to save a jpeg as an 8bit version instead of 16 bit or 24 bit.

I'm currently using imagecreate and then saving using imagejpeg but I can't see any parameters in the manual to allow for 8bit versions.

I've searched stackoverflow and php.net I find it hard to believe this isn't something easily achievable..

Thanks in advance

Comment: just realised I was doing something silly when testing which is why they came up as 16 bit not 8 bit. I was testing the wrong image.. oops. Sorry I'd self answer and close if I could but I can't for 7 hours its telling me

Comment: Do you mean 8 bits per pixel, or 8 bit color depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried imagemagic:

```
convert SRC.jpg -depth 8 -normalize  DEST.jpg
```

and with PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$SRC = 'src.jpg';
$DEST = 'dest.jpg';
$handle = popen("convert $SRC -depth 8 -normalize $DEST 2>&1", 'r');
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
pclose($handle);
?>
```